# Adding/removing rows from a table depending on true or false cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to add/remove rows to a table in excel automatically dependent on the value of a cell in another table on a different sheet.

For example;

On a seperate sheet I have one table with the following. This table contains all projects regardless of project outcome.

[image]

And then on another sheet I have a table containing all the entries that have been deemed a success.

[image]

I am trying to collate all projects that have been identified as a success to the above table. However, If I was to change Project1 to a Fail on the first table Project1 must be removed from the bottom table.

I have tried if statements but I can't seem to get the logic right. Would this have to be achieved through the use of a macro?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you choosing `Success` or `Fail`? By formula or manually?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for your response. This is done by a manual entry

Comment: If you use Excel365 you should have a Look to FILTER() - Function. If you use an older Version, take a Look to Special-Filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A VBA Solution

- The code runs automatically, you don't have to run anything. The code
  will run when you change the criteria values (`Success, Fail`). Keep in mind
  that the criteria is case sensitive.
- Copy the following code into the **sheet code** of the source sheet
  e.g. `Sheet1` and carefully adjust the 5 constants to fit your needs.

**Sheet Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2            ' Source/Target First Row Number
    Const Cols As String = "A:G"          ' Source/Target Columns Range Address
    Const CritCol As Long = 4             ' Criteria Column
    ' Note: If CritCol = n then it presents the n-th column of Columns Range,
    '       and not the n-th column of the worksheet.
    Const Criteria = "Success"            ' Criteria
    Const TargetName = "Sheet2"           ' Target Worksheet Name
    
    Dim SourceColumns As Range
    Set SourceColumns = Me.Columns(Cols)
    Dim CriteriaColumn As Long
    CriteriaColumn = getNthColumn(Me, SourceColumns.Address, CritCol)
    
    If CriteriaColumn = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Me.Columns(CriteriaColumn), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = getColumnRange(Me, CriteriaColumn, FirstRow)
    
    If Not Intersect(CriteriaRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
        Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetName)
        transferData SourceColumns, CriteriaRange, CritCol, Criteria, _
                     FirstRow, TargetSheet
    End If

End Sub
```

- Copy the following code into a standard module e.g. `Module1`.
  Nothing to change here.

**Module Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getColumnRange(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                        ByVal ColumnNumberOrLetter As Variant, _
                        Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(ColumnNumberOrLetter) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function      ' No data in whole column.
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Function  ' No data in and below first cell.
    Set getColumnRange = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, rng.Column), rng)
End Function

Function getNthColumn(Sheet As Worksheet, ByVal RangeAddress As String, _
                      Optional ByVal NthColumn As Long = 1) As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(RangeAddress)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rng.Columns.Count < NthColumn Then Exit Function
    getNthColumn = rng.Column + NthColumn - 1
End Function

Sub transferData(SourceColumns As Range, CriteriaColumnRange As Range, _
  CriteriaColumn As Long, Criteria As Variant, FirstRow As Long, _
  TargetSheet As Worksheet)
    
    Dim NoR As Long
    NoR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CriteriaColumnRange, Criteria)
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = Intersect(SourceColumns, CriteriaColumnRange.Rows.EntireRow)
    
    Dim Target As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ReDim Target(1 To NoR, 1 To UBound(Source, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
        If Source(i, CriteriaColumn) = Criteria Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(Source, 2)
                Target(k, j) = Source(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Erase Source
    
    With TargetSheet
        .Range(SourceColumns.Rows(FirstRow).Address).Resize( _
          .Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1).ClearContents
        .Range(SourceColumns.Rows(FirstRow).Address).Resize(k) = Target
    End With

End Sub
```